# Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type list. Defaulting to continuous

Tags: r, list, ggplot2

I'm stuck on plotting my data with ggplot. The outpit I have now is 16 obs. of 3 variables. I used unlist to make it a different data type but I still get errors to plot. My code:

```
library(datasets)
data(iris)
cluster_data<-iris[-5]

calcss <- function(missingvar,kval) {
    cluster<-kmeans(cluster_data[-missingvar],kval,nstart=100)
    TotWithinSS<-cluster$tot.withinss
    return(TotWithinSS)
}
kvals=list()
sumsqs=list()
missvars=list()
for(k in 2:5){
    for(var in 1:4){
       kvals=rbind(kvals,k)
       sumsqs=rbind(sumsqs,calcss(var,k))
       missvars=rbind(missvars,var)
    }
}
out<-data.frame(kvals,missvars,sumsqs)
ggplot(data=out,aes(missvars,sumsqs,color=kvals))
```

The error says:

Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type list. Defaulting to continuous.
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type list. Defaulting to continuous.
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type list. Defaulting to continuous.

Comment: Two things.  Initialise `kvals, sumsqs, missvars` as `numeric(0)` not as `list()`.  And add a geom to your plot, such as `+geom_point()`

Comment: Thank you! Works great now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `list` with `ggplot2`. It's also not recommended to grow your objects within `for` loop. It can get very slow if you have bigger data. See how to do it more efficiently [here](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2015/07/efficient-accumulation-in-r/) and [here](http://r-statistics.co/Strategies-To-Improve-And-Speedup-R-Code.html)

So you should pre-allocate the size of your objects before `for` loop with either `rep` or `vector`

```r
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)

data(iris)
cluster_data <- iris[-5]

calcss <- function(missingvar, kval) {
  cluster <- kmeans(cluster_data[-missingvar], kval, nstart = 100)
  TotWithinSS <- cluster$tot.withinss
  return(TotWithinSS)
}

kvals = rep(NA, 16) # or use kvals = vector("numeric", 16L)
sumsqs = rep(NA, 16)
missvars = rep(NA, 16)

for(k in 2:5) {
  for(var in 1:4) {
    kvals = rbind(kvals, k)
    sumsqs = rbind(sumsqs, calcss(var, k))
    missvars = rbind(missvars, var)
  }
}

out <- data.frame(kvals, missvars, sumsqs)

ggplot(data = out, aes(missvars, sumsqs, color = kvals)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-31 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks, Tung. I'll take a look at your links